# Why featured tab shows the count wrongly?

Tags: discussion, support, status-bydesign

When ever I checked the featured tab, It shows the count wrongly, If I check this count with the below paths also shows different count

1.) http://drupal.stackexchange.com and

2.) https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions

I know this is because of cache or cron job, but I want to know is this normal ?

[image]

> [image]

Comment: Difference between 12 and 13 is hardly significant. Difference between 1 or none would matter, but when there are a lot of them anyway, an hour of cache lag is not really a problem, even if it's irritating ;)

Comment: it's always caching... or some bounty expiring / being awarded between those 2 screenshots